# Expression for Sum of Multivariate Gaussian Random Vectors

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, machine-learning, pattern-recognition

Consider two multidimensional random vectors $x$ and $z$ having Gaussian distributions $P(x)=N(x\mid\mu_x,\Sigma_x)$ and $P(z)=N(z\mid\mu_z,\Sigma_z)$, respectively, together with their sum $y=x+z$. Find an expression for the marginal distribution $P(y)$ by considering the linear-Gaussian model comprising the product of the marginal distribution $P(x)$ and the conditional distribution $P(y\mid x)$.

Comment: Rather late, but just adding for completeness: the mean of the distribution would be the sum of the means and its variance would be the sum of variances (squared standard deviations).

Answer (score 1):

Is it me, or can one forget all the specifics of the question and simply rely on the well-known Bayes formula $f_Y(y)=\displaystyle\int f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)f_X(x)\mathrm dx$?